# Visual Studio Online test runner can't load SpecFlow dll

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I've added SpecFlow using Nuget and have a single spec (so it is a simple project). I've created a build in VS online 2015 using the web build editor.

Maybe it's a Nuget new build system issue? I'm not sure if it just a SpecFlow thing and haven't gotten a chance try straight MS unit tests yet.

> An exception occurred while invoking executor
> 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Could not load file or assembly
> 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.9.0.77, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.

Here's a larger stack trace:

```
1. 2015-08-03T21:26:27.6325511Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\tasks\VSTest\1.0.16\VSTest.ps1
2. 2015-08-03T21:26:28.4231183Z ##[debug]Calling Invoke-VSTest for all test assemblies
3. 2015-08-03T21:26:28.4481177Z Working folder: C:\a\14076a40
4. 2015-08-03T21:26:28.4481177Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\a\14076a40\SpecByExample\SpecByExample.Specs\bin\Debug\SpecByExample.Specs.dll" "C:\a\14076a40\SpecByExample\SpecByExample.Specs\bin\Debug\SpecByExample.Specs.dll.config" "C:\a\14076a40\SpecByExample\SpecByExample.Specs\obj\Debug\SpecByExample.Specs.dll"  /logger:trx
5. 2015-08-03T21:26:29.4654019Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0
6. 2015-08-03T21:26:29.4664025Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
7. 2015-08-03T21:26:29.4664025Z Starting test execution, please wait...
8. 2015-08-03T21:26:29.7564024Z Warning: Unable to load types from the test source 'C:\a\14076a40\SpecByExample\SpecByExample.Specs\obj\Debug\SpecByExample.Specs.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered. If you are running unit tests for Windows Store apps and referencing custom WinMD type then please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238340 for more info. Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SpecResults, Version=0.1.0.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
9. 2015-08-03T21:26:29.7574029Z .
10. 2015-08-03T21:26:40.6922424Z Passed   TheUserVisitsTheWebsite
11. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.3214684Z ##[error]Error: An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.9.0.77, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
12. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.3224680Z ##[error]
13. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.4936886Z Results File: C:\a\14076a40\TestResults\buildguest_TASKAGENT-0007 2015-08-03 21_26_40.trx
14. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.4956876Z Total tests: 1. Passed: 1. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
15. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.4966881Z ##[error]Test Run Failed.
16. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.4966881Z Test execution time: 11.8787 Seconds
17. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.7581094Z ##[error]VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 1
18. 2015-08-03T21:26:41.7741099Z Publishing Test Results...

2015-08-03T21:26:43.0372165Z Test results remaining: 1
```

UPDATE: I disabled the SpecFlow test and added the simplest AboutController test possible (from file new project MVC in Visual Studio). I still get a 'could not load assembly problem. SpecByExample.Web is my MVC project in my solution.

> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7251975Z ##[error]Error Message:
> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7261978Z ##[error]   Test method
> SpecByExample.Web.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTests.AboutTest
> threw exception:    2015-08-07T16:16:56.7261978Z
>
> ### [error]System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SpecByExample.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>
> PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
> find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7271982Z ##[error]To enable assembly bind failure
> logging, set the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7271982Z ##[error]Note: There is some performance
> penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7281979Z ##[error]To turn this feature off, remove
> the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7281979Z ##[error]   2015-08-07T16:16:56.7291971Z
>
> ### [error]Stack Trace:   2015-08-07T16:16:56.7291971Z ##[error]    at SpecByExample.Web.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTests.AboutTest()
>
> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7831986Z Results File:
> C:\a\14076a40\TestResults\buildguest_TASKAGENT-0007 2015-08-07
> 16_16_56.trx   2015-08-07T16:16:56.7861977Z Attachments:
> 2015-08-07T16:16:56.7861977Z ##[error]Test Run Failed.

Here's a screenshot of my build definition:
[image]

Comment: have you solved that issue ?

Comment: I haven't, it fell off my radar, so I haven't tried it for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

In Run unit test step. click advance and give path to your packages folder. (if you are using nuget it will download all dependencies there) give it a try and let me know how it goes. [image: sample image with path]

Comment: I put in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SpecByExample.Web\packages and getThe path 'C:\a\14076a40\SpecByExample\SpecByExample.Web\packages' specified in the 'TestAdapterPath' is invalid.
 $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages gets a msbuild exit code of 1

Comment: $(Build.SourcesDirectory) is where source is hosted. so after the it should be solution directory and after that packages folder.